# Airflow worker pod keeps restarting after upgrading to Cloud Composer2.1.8-Airflow2.2.5

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-composer

Cloud composer2.1.8-airflow2.2.5 airflow worker restart issue

After perform in-place upgrade cloud composer version operation from composer2.0.19-airflow2.2.5 to composer2.1.8-airflow2.2.5, the following problems are found:

1. The airflow worker become very unstable. Even only a few airflow tasks (10-15) execute at the same time the airflow worker pod will be kill and restart.
2. After the airflow worker is restarted, these airflow tasks in the queued state should continue to be pick up by airflow worker and execute theoretically. but the airflow worker doesn't pick up the queued state task. These tasks in the queued state will remain in the queue until we manually perform "airflow clear" operation to clean these task and rerun.

I try to debug this issue refer by https://cloud.google.com/composer/docs/composer-2/troubleshooting-dags and have increase our airflow worker resource (1 cpu -> 2 cpu, 2 gb mem -> 4 gb mem), but airflow worker restart issue still happen.

I found that airlfow worker monitor's cpu and memory metric seems don't exceed the limit. but airflow worker still fail and restart in 8:00~9:00 am.

[airflow monitor metrics1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x0R0y.png)

[airflow monitor metrics2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GecK.png)

I also check whether GKE container have OOM  or not.  perform this log query

```
resource.type="k8s_node"
    log_id("events")
    (jsonPayload.reason:("OOMKilling" OR "SystemOOM")
      OR jsonPayload.message:("OOM encountered" OR "out of memory"))
    severity=WARNING
    resource.labels.cluster_name="us-west1-airflow-dev-61e7af4b-gke"
```

and I found that it really have OOM error before airlfow worker pod restart. but i don't find that any log about airlfow worker memory exceed.

[cloud logging1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzsDk.png)

[cloud logging2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZgWza.png)

Hope that anyone can help me identify this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://cloud.google.com/knowledge/kb/google-kubernetes-engine-error-message-warning-oomkilling-memory-cgroup-out-of-memory-000004697) to resolve GKE's OOM issue?

Comment: no, I can't. because cloud composer2 GKE cluster is autopilot mode. i can't adjust node operation. But when i add more resources to airflow worker (2 workers -> 4 workers, 2G memory -> 4G memory) it seems like no error occur....